# Is there a way to store INT and strings in the same array?

Tags: c++, hex

I'm not sure how parsing works, nor have I been able to do it in C++.

I've created an algorithm that converts decimals to hexadecimals. The algorithm right now still outputs values bigger than 9, like `10` instead of `A`. The following function was supposed to deal with the issue but when I run it through, I can't store the normal 1-9 values with the As and Bs in the same array, which means I can't output them. I've been stuck on this for 2 days.

```cpp
string hexValues(int remainder)
{
    string A = "A";
    string B = "B";
    string C = "C";
    string D = "D";
    string E = "E";
    string F = "F";

    if (remainder == 10)
    {
        return A;
    }
    else if (remainder == 11)
    {
        return B;
    }
    else if (remainder == 12)
    {
        return C;
    }
    else if (remainder == 13)
    {
        return D;
    }
    else if (remainder == 14)
    {
        return E;
    }
    else if (remainder == 15)
    {
        return F;
    }
}
```

```
 hexMod = userDecNumber4Hex % 16;
            if (hexMod > 9)
            {
                hexadecimalAnswer[y] = hexValues(hexMod);
            }
            else
            {
                hexadecimalAnswer[y] = hexMod;
            }


    while (userDecNumber4Hex != 0)
    {
        if (userDecNumber4Hex % 16 != 0)
        {
            hexMod = userDecNumber4Hex % 16;
            if (hexMod > 9)
            {
                hexadecimalAnswer[y] = hexValues(hexMod);
            }
            else
            {
                hexadecimalAnswer[y] = hexMod;
            }

            userDecNumber4Hex = (userDecNumber4Hex-hexMod)/ 16;
            y += 1;
        }
        else if (userDecNumber4Hex % 16 == 0)
        {
            userDecNumber4Hex = userDecNumber4Hex / 16; 
            if (userDecNumber4Hex > 9)
            {
                hexadecimalAnswer[y] = userDecNumber4Hex;
            }

        }

    }
```

the code is long so i wasn't really sure what to post but there are multiple arrays- but its just one of them that i need to have store the values getting from the hexValues function, while it already has int values

Comment: This has nothing to do with "storing int and strings in the same array", although C++17 has a template that can be used to do that. If your "remainder" is 3, for example, then simply return "3". That's how conversion to hexadecimal works. If you want to have an array of 16 values, it's just an array of `std::string`s: `{"0","1",'2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"}`.

Comment: There's no array in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integers in your hexadecimal number are only going to range between `0` and `9`, you can store them as characters. At the same time, you can store `A`-`F` as characters as well. 
Therefore, instead return characters as the face values.

```
char hexValues (int remainder)
{
    if (remainder < 10)
        return '0' + remainder;
    else 
        return 'A' + (remainder - 10);
}
```

For full conversion, here's a good excuse to use Recursion:

```
string decToHex (int n)
{
     if (n < 16)
     {
         string s (1, decToHex (n));
         return s;
     }
     else 
         return decToHex (n / 16) + hexValues (n % 16);
}
```

Comment: I couldn't upload a picture, but the outputs are now just a little boxes with a little question marks inside.

Comment: @Teddles Are you sure that `remainder` is ranging between `0`-`15`?

Comment: yes! if i remove the "hexValues" function and run the algorithm normally , it still converts decimals to hexadecimals but instead of 1A , it'll write 110- which of course i know is 1 and 10 but it looks like 110

Comment: I'd love to but i'm unsure whether or not i'll get penalised by my teacher for it and I dont wanna risk failing the assignment, but i can show you the algorithm that deals with the hexadecimals.

Comment: Im probably mistaken but this doesn't seem to be look like it'd deal with numbers that aren't a factor of 16 . I'm unsure though

Comment: @Teddles In C++, ```n / 16``` is ```n // 16``` (divide and floor) for non-negative integer types. Your result stays an `int`.

Comment: So interestingly- the letters are coming out normal but the numbers are still little boxes with little question marks inside them.

Comment: is there a way to upload a picture here so i can show you

Comment: @Teddles You can upload it on imgur and send me a link

Comment: https://imgur.com/Xbx8nRn

sorry it took a while, I had to register.

Comment: https://imgur.com/T0iD4sP

https://imgur.com/r1gBxyA

they're just your algorithms - but i made sure the input would only use the A value, input is 26 , which is just 1A i believe.

Comment: @Teddles I've made a small change in my algorithm, can you see if that works?

Comment: @Teddles But it's working alright on Ideone: check this link - https://ideone.com/Uk86W8

Comment: @Teddles Can you upload a clearer picture? The errors are not readable. The picture is unreadable due to its low-quality.